# How can I use PHP-FPM from a bash script?

Tags: php, bash, fpm

I know `php-fpm` isn't intended to be used from `bash` as much as, say, `php-cli`, but I'm making a common interface for my website from both my broswer and the command line, and I need the executing version to be exactly the same.

```
echo '<?php echo 1' | socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

doesn't work, but I guess it is maybe because I don't extract the output, but either way I wouldn't know how to do that.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why can't you just ensure that the `php.ini` for both `php-fpm` and `php-cli` are the same?

Comment: I could, but that would make me unable to see php-fpm-related errors. dumb things such as php service turned off.

Comment: Use other mechanisms to monitor your PHP-FPM service.

Comment: That isn't an option, because it lets users wrongly use the deployed solution on other servers.

Answer (score 1):

You should not. As @Barmar pointed out in the comments, just ensure `php-cli` has the same `php.ini` file loaded as `php-fpm`. Then just call `php` from bash. For me, the solution in an docker environment was to add the last line in this example docker-compose.yml

```
    php-fpm:
        build: phpdocker/php-fpm
        working_dir: /app
        environment:
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
        volumes:
            - '../xy:/xy'
            - './phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini'
            - './phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-overrides.ini'
```

Where `/phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini` is my custom ini file.

Comment: Oh boy, time flies